# Ideas about persistence for non-logged in users

Tags: blazor

My edu-site (server hosted) has a collection of multiplayer games that I'd like unregistered users to be able to try.  Passers-by on the street will be presented with posters with QR codes that will take them straight into the game section without having to register.

The players must choose and customize an avatar and temporary name when they go to the page, and then they can select a game to join.  But if they reload or timeout, they are out and must create a new avatar again.  That will likely result in an immediate loss of interest, and potentially a customer.

**My question:
How to best persist state even across reloads for guest users who are not logged in.**

I'm thinking about:

- logging IP address of each circuit with a popup on reload: "This IP is currently in a registered game.  Re-join?"
- creating a temporary user and logging them into it, then deleting the temp user after the game is finished
- using cookies but without creating any user object

Any ideas on which way is best, or another way?  The only absolute no-go is that I do NOT want to force users to fill out any kind of registration form.  They'll have a chance to do that after they've tried some games.

Comment: Oops I should mention that it's Server flavor.  I will add that in edit rn.

Comment: Take a look at using local storage - it's insanely easy with Blazor: https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage

Comment: I've already committed to creating guest accounts, but that's something I will definitely make use of soon.

Comment: Oh yeah - you'll need a temp user in the backend (or, at least, that's a perfectly sensible approach). I'm just suggesting using local storage to store the id of the temp user (i.e. use it for the same thing you would use cookies for). As long as it's a random guid it should be secure enough for your purposes (as there is no PMI or similar associated with the temp user).

Comment: I've got maybe 10k lines in my site, and I'm still learning a lot.  I assumed local storage was for WASM only.

Comment: Local Storage is a JavaScript feature that gives you a handy place to store data client-side (i.e. think of it as a little database inside the user's browser). You can use it with WASM or Server and it will let you store your "client-id" or whatever data you need. So, create a user in the backend, store the id in local storage, and then, whenever they refresh the session and you don't know who they are, just ask local storage for the client id. If it doesn't have one they are a new user.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like a very good solution.  I could definitely achieve my stated goal using that method.  It occurs to me that my user settings (font and font size, in particular) are currently stored server-side, because I didn't want to use cookies.  But surely per-device-user data would be better.

Comment: I think that's exactly the sort of data that makes sense in user-storage. Be aware though that if the user changes browser, or opens an incognito window, or clears their local-storage, all those settings will be lost. Personally, I think that's a good thing for this sort of data, but worth bearing in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this turned out to be a good chance to learn about Middleware in Blazor.

Honestly, I was surprised how easy it was.  Before the request even hits the Blazor engine, you have access to HTTPContext, .NET membership methods, and everything else you need.

The following intercepts a request to serve the `games` page if it has no `user` with a UserID, creates a new user with the prefix "guest_", and logs the user into that account before releasing it to the rest of the pipeline.

**GuesIDMiddleware.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APP.Code.Gaming
{
    public class GuestIdMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public async Task Invoke (HttpContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager)
        {
            var UserID = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value;

            if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/games" && UserID is null)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = "guest_" + Guid.NewGuid(), Email = "guest@beclub.kr", EmailConfirmed = true };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                if (result.Succeeded)
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
            }
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        public GuestIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

And literally only requires the following in **System.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // . . .
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseMiddleware<GuestIdMiddleware>();
        // . . .
    }
```